# ios open image on button click

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I am creating a program where images are shown in collection view grid, 
as i tap/click on particular image it should open in another scroll view. 
I am creating cells in collection view dynamically. anybody have any ideas regarding that ? thanks in advance.

Comment: what you want exactly?

Comment: So basically you're trying to do this ?http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/CollectionView-Simple/Listings/CollectionView_Cell_h.html

Comment: Pratik: if i click on one image , that image should be open in other scroll view

Comment: yes exactly. thats what i want to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Man just download this code

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/CollectionView-Simple/Listings/CollectionView_Cell_h.html

start it and in DetailViewController.m where
`self.imageView.image = self.image;`
you just put a `scrollView` programmatically and add the `imageView` in it

Comment: @user2147631 from the example I've send, go to the storyboard and add Scroll View, then add the Image View in that Scroll View. Adjust the properties of the Scroll View, like bounce vertical, user interaction EST.

Answer (score 1):

use tap gestures

```
 UITapGestureRecognizer *PressRecognizer1 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePress:)];
            [PressRecognizer1 setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
             [imageview addGestureRecognizer:PressRecognizer1];
```

write your code in this method

```
-(void)handlePress:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)PressRecognizer {

    NSLog(@"working");

   //Add your code here for click on particular image

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement following method of UICollectionViewDelegate

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

The method will be called when user taps on a item.

Do not forget to setting delegate.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply adding an image and using `UIButton` ?

```
[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(callNewController:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` delegate method.

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    // TODO: Here you need to allocate the next view and pass the image then show the view
}
```